# How to disable providers from Package Discovery?

Tags: laravel-5

Whenever I wanted to add functionality to a class in Laravel, lets say the Filesystem class, I would create my own class:

```
class FilesystemServiceProvider extends LaravelFilesystemManager{
```

and add it to my `provider`array in **config/app.php** and disable the original:

```
<?php

    'providers' => [

//        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'MyApp\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    ],
```

If I have a package from composer that is bind by [Package Discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#package-discovery) how can I prevent it from being discovered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are the consumer of a package and would like to disable package discovery for a package, you may list the package name in the extra section of your application's composer.json file:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar"
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: How about an Illuminate package?